# Bluemix cloudant gradle packages for Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Alright, So.
I'm looking to do a query to request some json packets from my bluemix cloudant to my app in Android studio.
I tried following these instructions:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/cloud/data/t_data_cloudantlocalsetup.html
But the provided package links don't seem to be in Maven when i type it into gradle.
If the packages no longer exist or aren't supported, How would i approach doing the same requests with http?

Comment: It looks like you are following the Cloudant Local docs. You are going to want to use these instead, https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-getting-started#getting-started.

Comment: The current bluemix UI looks nothing like in that tutorial, I cannot find half the settings that this tutorial is describing. The java syntax also works nothing like the python syntax either, Also, to top it off: I need to run my networking code on a separate hread because of Android's security.

Comment: That was pointing to IBM Cloudant docs instead of the Mobile First documentation (an on-premises product.) Here are the Java/Android docs, https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two Cloudant libraries available in Maven central that can be used in Android.

1. [java-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant); `compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-client', version: '2.16.0'`
2. [sync-android](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android); `compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version:'latest.release'`

The first is a Java library which can be used for making HTTP requests against a remote Cloudant or Apache CouchDB.
The second is a sync library which can use Apache CouchDB's replication protocol to create a local copy of a database on device for use with, for example, offline use cases that sync back to the remote database.